# Bug - "Copied" toast notification when opening my app - Android 13 devices

Tags: android, clipboard, toast

I'm working on an app and whenever I open it, there's a "Copied" toast notification pops up.  It doesn't actually copy any content to clipboard. Please see link to screenshot here.

[image: 1]

There're people online talking about workarounds  (KDE Connect, etc.) but those are for their own devices as users. This behavior doesn't happen on other apps so I suspect certain setting in my app leads to this.

I'm new to mobile development so appreciate if any direction suggested so that I could investigate my app setting further.